# How can I split word in the wav file in python?

Tags: python, audio, nlp, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

e.g wav file is("How are you ?") ı want to  split 3 wav file like as  ("How"), ("are"), ("you").Could you help me  ?

Comment: This is not a trivial problem; unlike written text, words don't have clear boundaries in speech, unless the speaker leaves a deliberate pause between each word. In real speech, words run into each other acoustically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but you need to know the timestamp of each word, unless you use machine learning. If you know the time stamps at the end of each word, for example, after how it's 1, after are its 2 and after you its 2.7, try this.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

stamps = [1,2,2.7] #timestamps at end of each word

originalAudio = AudioSegment.from_wav("audiofile.wav")
start = 0
counter = 1
for current in stamps:
    newAudio = originalAudio[start*1000: current*1000] #in milliseconds 
    newAudio.export(f'{counter}-word.wav', format="wav") 
    counter += 1
    start = current
```

The files will be saved as 1-word.wav, 2-word.wav etc.

If you don’t know the timings, you can try this code, it listens for silences or pauses.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence

sound_file = AudioSegment.from_wav("sentence.wav")
audio_chunks = split_on_silence(sound_file, 
    # must be silent for at least half a second
    # make it shorter if the pause is short, like 100-250ms
    min_silence_len=500,

    # consider it silent if quieter than -16 dBFS
    silence_thresh=16
)

for i, chunk in enumerate(audio_chunks):

    out_file = f"chunk{i}.wav"
    print ("exporting", out_file)
    chunk.export(out_file, format="wav")
```

However, after listening to the audio file, there is a lot of background noise and no clear pauses between words.

You then said that you want to translate the audio to text, try this code.

First install the required libraries.

```
pip3 install SpeechRecognition pydub
```

Then run this,

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

audiofile = 'demo55.wav'

with sr.AudioFile(audiofile) as source:
    # listen for the data (load audio to memory)
    audio_data = r.record(source)
    # recognize (convert from speech to text) tr is code for turkish
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data, language="tr-tr")
    print(text)
```

I get the output,

```
"Merhaba benim adım Ezgi"
```

Not sure if this is correct as I don't speak turkish, but i listened to it and it sounds correct.

Comment: I try this code ,  it is build  0 sn wav file but it doesn't have word. How can ı do this with machine learning ? Please help me .

Comment: Sorry wait let me update my code

Comment: You need to know when each word ends in the wav file, do you have the file ?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn’t have word??

Comment: Yes ı have a file but I dont know when each word ends in the wav file. Because I sometimes record to with  microphone. I doesnt have word means to I cant  play 1-word.wav, 2-word.wav wav file because the wav length is 0 sec.

Comment: I updated my code, so you know how long the silence or pause is after each word ?

Comment: No I dont know , New code splited the wav file to 3 wav file but first wav file hav 4 words.

Comment: Maybe reduce the number from 500 to 250

Comment: Why can't it enter the for  loop in the second code you sent?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean, which part ??

Comment: What’s the error

Comment: I updated the code take a look again

Comment: This row (" for i, chunk in enumerate(audio_chunks): ") is didnt run.

Comment: Because I added print("a") under the for loop , ı dont saw "a",. This is mean code didnt run in the for loop

Comment: Try the updated code

Comment: I dont saw print("exporting", out_file) why ?

Comment: Yes , I try to updated code

Comment: Audio chunks is received the  this   [ ] .

Comment: Can you share the file with me? The audio file

Comment: Yes ı can but How ? I can share the file from the here ?

Comment: Upload to Dropbox or google drive

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RPXwfsWYv162ropwKLhA-5ShYfZ68A2J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I will wait your return

Comment: hi, so i listened to your file @ezgiozgur, the problem is there is a lot of background noise so there is no silence between words. you could try increasing the silence threshold

Comment: @ezgiozgur you could try 16 db instead of -16db.

Comment: @ezgiozgur what language is this?

Comment: @ezgiozgur you can use machine learning to translate the words into text, but i am not sure about breaking the file into different words.

Comment: This is Turkish language. How can ı use the machine learning to translate the word into the text ? I have a big problem about this question. How can ı this ? what is the first ,second... step in this project e.g

Comment: I’ll give you the code when I go home; translation is easy

Comment: I will wait your return

Comment: @ezgiozgur hey check out my answer, just updated it.

Comment: But I dont want to use the google api  so I use to machine learning. And My project understand to words but Dont undertsand sentences so  I want to split wav file like word to word. 
In this way, it will understand the words and when they are combined, those words will understand the sentence